# How to filter contacts according to tags in views in Drupal 8 with CiviCRM entity?

Tags: civicrm-entity, drupal-8, tags

I want to be able to filter organizations by tags. However, the reference in "Relations" is not available for tags even though it exists for groups : "CiviCRM Tags uses created_id" exists but not "CiviCRM Tags uses contact_id" as for CiviCRM Group.

Can you explain to me ?

Thank you for your help